# Unified Functional Testing: How to schedule a .tsp file to run?

Tags: vba, hp-uft, uft14

I have a .tsp file that uses GUI to test out applications and I need it to run everyday.

The thing is, only UFT is able to recognize the file type. Outside of UFT, the file is just a folder with many files inside it so I can't use Windows Task Scheduler to run it.

Would there be a way to schedule it by either using a built-in UFT tool or using some sort of outside script to open UFT and run it?

Comment: Sorry, the script I am using uses VBA and its the only thing I can write in.

Answer (score 0):

UFT supports [scheduling tests](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.51/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Jenkins.htm) with Jenkins.